# MySQL mylfunctions

Tags: mysql, function

I have created this code using MySQL within a "mylibrary" database but when I turned it in the professor said that the function had nothing to do with the database and it seemed to be missing some statements.  Could some of you take a look at this code and tell me what I am missing in order for the information to work properly?

delimiter $$
adds number of titles to the qty count

```
create function titleCount_5(number INT,qty INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
RETURN number+number;
END $$
delimiter ;

select titleCount_5(5,8);
```

Comment: you are not selecting anything from the DB , et al

Comment: also, not doing anything with the QTY parameter supplied to the function.

Comment: All this function does is double the first argument. `select titleCount_5(5,8);` will net you `10`. Conversely, `select titleCount_5(8,5);` will get you `16`. I can't imagine you'd really want to create a user function for doubling a number--what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a function with two parameters, I would like to place an authors name such as "Chris" and return how many titles he has.  I tried varchar with author and then ended up with this.  Obviously this nor the other worked.